# I'm unable to activate a C# button by the press of an Keyboard key

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm able to click on a button and have it activate, yet when I release a keyboard key my button doesn't activate. The code is C#,and I'm using VS 2015

```
   private void btnApiBetHigh_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F)
        {
            CurrentSite.amount = ((decimal)nudApiBet.Value);
            CurrentSite.chance = (decimal)(nudApiChance.Value);
            CurrentSite.PlaceBet(true, (decimal)nudApiBet.Value, (decimal)(nudApiChance.Value));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the button have the focus when you press the key?

Comment: Why do you want to activate the button by pressing `F` when the button has focus? What's your requirement?

Comment: @Andrew Morton  Focus?

Comment: The control with focus is the one which accepts input. For example, you can tab to a control to give it focus (it is often shown by highlighting that control).

Comment: @Reza Aghaei It's for betting. I want to Press "F" to bet High, and I'll use similar code to have the key "G" bet low.

Comment: Have you set the `KeyPreview` property on the form (assuming this is a WinForms project?)

Comment: You don't need to handle `KeyUp` event of the `Button`. Instead, override `ProcessCmdKey` method of form.

Comment: @Andrew Morton It works when the button has been clicked but not before.

Comment: @user208204 - it works when the button has been clicked because the button has focus and hence the keyup handler will fire. You need to to follow the steps in either of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the property `KeyPreview` of the form to `true`. Then use your code in the `KeyUp` event of the Form, not of the individual buttons.

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if(e.KeyCode == Keys.F)
     {
          e.Handled = true;
          MessageBox.Show("F"); 
     }
     else if(e.KeyCode  == Keys.G)
     {
          e.Handled = true;
          MessageBox.Show("G");
     }
}
```

---

Another way without writing any code is to use [mnemonics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/190kw3at.aspx). If you use the text "Bet High (&G)" for the button, the button is automatically pressed when you press the G key anywhere on the form (except when a control is focused that accepts text input).

Comment: When using mnemonic, the button will be activated by pressing `Alt + Key`. Just when the button have focus, pressing mnemonic Key without `Alt` fires click event of button :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei It will also work without ALT when the button doesn't have focus as long as the currently focused control is not a textbox, combobox or other control that accepts text input itself. Test it :)

Comment: Not a `TextBox` and `ComboBox` and other controls that accepts text. It's enough description ;)